# Polynomiality of the equivariant Euler characteristic of a sheaf tensored with a standard line bundle on the flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, equivariant-cohomology, flag-varieties, euler-characteristics

Let ${\mathcal B}=Fl(V)$ be the variety of complete flags in an $(m+2n)$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C$. Then we have the standard line bundles $\mathcal{O}(\lambda)$ on $\mathcal B$ for weights $\lambda$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_{m+2n}$. Let the vector space $V$ have basis $e_1,...,e_{m+n}, f_1,..., f_n$. Let ${\mathbb C}^*$ act on $V$ by $t \cdot e_i = t^{-2i} e_i$, $t \cdot f_i = t^{-2i} f_i$. This action of ${\mathbb C}^*$ on $V$ induces an action on $Fl(V)$. Non-equivaraintly, it is known that for a fixed bounded complex of coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathcal{B}$ we have $\chi(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}(\lambda))$ is a polynomial $d_{\mathcal F}(\lambda)$ in $\lambda$. It is also known that for line bundles this polynomial is given by the Weyl dimension formula. (The last two facts are presented in Lemma 6.2.6 in Bezrukavnikov, Mirkovic, and Rumynin https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205144 )

My question is, is it true that for a fixed equivariant bounded complex of coherent sheaves on $\mathcal B$ the equivariant Euler characteristic $\chi_{\mathbb C^*}(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}(\lambda))$ is  a polynomial in two variables $d_{\mathcal F}^{\prime}(\lambda,t)$? Does this have anything to do with the Weyl character formula?

Comment: The geometric Lefschetz fixed point formula (see the article of Baum-Fulton-MacPherson) shows that this is a rational function with rational coefficients and with variables $\lambda$ and $t^{a\lambda+b}$, where $a,b$ are integers. The Weyl character formula can be deduced from the fixed point formula. See eg http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/math-library/schmid/schmid-character-formulas-localization-integrals-1997.pdf